# TFS 2013 - Change default retention policy for all build definitions

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When you create a new build definition the Retention Policy is set to "Keep 10 Latest" for Failed, Partially Succeeded and Succeeded builds. Is there a way to change to change those default values globally? We have around 80 builds. Keeping all those builds stored take a ton of space. I'd like to keep only the last two or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Community TFS Build Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f) for massive edit.

Answer (score 0):

Retention Policies are stored on each Build Definition.  So, unfortunately, you cannot change the retention policies for a set of existing build definitions.  However, you can make it easier when creating new ones by cloning existing ones.  `Right-click` on an existing build definition and click `Clone Build Definition`.